# android studioでのエラー（Duplicate resources）について

Tags: android

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> [mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png [mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.webp: Error: Duplicate resources
  [mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher_round.png [mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher_round.webp: Error: Duplicate resources
  [mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png [mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.webp: Error: Duplicate resources
  [mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher_round.png [mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher_round.webp: Error: Duplicate resources
  [mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png   [mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.webp: Error: Duplicate resources
  [mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png   [mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher_round.webp: Error: Duplicate resources
  [mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png [mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.webp: Error: Duplicate resources
  [mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png [mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher_round.webp: Error: Duplicate resources
  [mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png   [mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.webp: Error: Duplicate resources
  [mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher_round.png   [mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_round] C:\Users\berdy\AndroidStudioProjects\MySize\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher_round.webp: Error: Duplicate resources

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 1):

`ic_launcher` と が `ic_launcher_round` が、それぞれ `.png` と `.webp` の 2 種類あるのが原因でしょうね。どちらか一方を残して、他は削除またはリネームするなどしてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: Cause: received handshake warning: unrecognized_name 消してみたらこんなエラーが出たんですが、なぜでしょうか？

Comment: @dio それはまた別件のエラー（SSL 関係？）でしょうね。今回のエラーが解消され、これまでの状態ではストップして進んでいなかった処理が先に進み、別のエラーに遭遇したのでしょう。一応、今回の質問では、Duplicate resources エラーについてのものでしたから、この質問は解決済みとして閉じて、改めてそのエラーについて必要な情報（エラーログや関係するプログラムコードを掲載した）質問を立ててください。